# Consumer doesn't update the UI when using notifyListeners()

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, state-management

I'm using animated containers and I want them to change color when I use NotifyListeners();
Thing is, the color only updates when you click on the container, otherwise it remains the same.

I tried switching to normal containers, I tried changing the home screen to stateful, nothing seems to work, any help is appreciated.

Github link: https://github.com/amrogad/beat_maker

```
void main() {
  runApp(MultiProvider(providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider<SoundProvider>(create: (_) => SoundProvider(),
    ),
    ChangeNotifierProvider<IconProvider>(create: (_) => IconProvider(),
    ),
  ], child: MyApp()));
}
```

```
class IconProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  Color primary1 = Colors.deepPurpleAccent;
  Color secondary1 = Colors.deepPurple;
  Color primary2 = Colors.yellowAccent;
  Color secondary2 = Colors.orangeAccent;
  Color primary3 = Colors.cyanAccent;
  Color secondary3 = Colors.blue;
  Color primary4 = Colors.lime;
  Color secondary4 = Colors.lightGreen;


  void changeIcons(
    Color primaryPath1,
    Color secondaryPath1,
    Color primaryPath2,
    Color secondaryPath2,
    Color primaryPath3,
    Color secondaryPath3,
    Color primaryPath4,
    Color secondaryPath4,
  ) {
    primary1 = primaryPath1;
    secondary1 = secondaryPath1;
    primary2 = primaryPath2;
    secondary2 = secondaryPath2;
    primary3 = primaryPath3;
    secondary3 = secondaryPath3;
    primary4 = primaryPath4;
    secondary4 = secondaryPath4;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String routeName = 'Home Screen';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var soundProvider = Provider.of<SoundProvider>(context);
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        appBar: AppBar(
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          title: Text(
            'Beat Maker',
            style: GoogleFonts.anton(color: Colors.lime, fontSize: 24),
          ),
          centerTitle: true,
          actions: [
            GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(SettingsScreen.routeName);
                },
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.settings,
                  color: Colors.lime,
                  size: 24,
                )),
            SizedBox(
              width: 10,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: Consumer<IconProvider>(
          builder: (context, icon, child) {
            return GridView(
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 4
              ),
              children: [
                SoundButton(
                    icon.primary1, icon.secondary1, soundProvider.note1),
                SoundButton(
                    icon.primary2, icon.secondary2, soundProvider.note2),
                SoundButton(
                    icon.primary3, icon.secondary3, soundProvider.note3),
                SoundButton(
                    icon.primary4, icon.secondary4, soundProvider.note4)
              ],
            );
          }
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

```
class SoundButton extends StatefulWidget {
  final Color mainColor;
  final Color sideColor;
  final note;

  const SoundButton(this.mainColor, this.sideColor, this.note, {Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SoundButton> createState() => _SoundButtonState();
}

class _SoundButtonState extends State<SoundButton> {
  late Color _mainColor;
  late Color _sideColor;
  final player = AudioPlayer();

  @override
  void initState() {
    _mainColor = widget.mainColor;
    _sideColor = widget.sideColor;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          _mainColor = Colors.redAccent;
          _sideColor = Colors.red;
          player.play(AssetSource(widget.note));
        });
      },
      child: AnimatedContainer(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(width: 1),
            gradient: RadialGradient(colors: [_mainColor, _sideColor]),
            boxShadow: const [
              BoxShadow(
                blurRadius: 1.0,
                spreadRadius: 1.0,
                offset: Offset(
                  1.0,
                  1.0,
                ),
              ),
            ]),
        curve: Curves.easeOutCubic,
        onEnd: () => Reset(),
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
      ),
    );
  }

  void Reset() {
    setState(() {
      _mainColor = widget.mainColor;
      _sideColor = widget.sideColor;
    });
  }
}
```

```
class OpenIconBottomSheet extends StatelessWidget {
  const OpenIconBottomSheet({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var iconProvider = Provider.of<IconProvider>(context);
    return Container(
      height: 106,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(12), topRight: Radius.circular(12)),
          color: Colors.black,
          border: Border.all(width: 3, color: Colors.lime)),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                iconProvider.changeIcons(
                  Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
                  Colors.deepPurple,
                  Colors.yellowAccent,
                  Colors.orangeAccent,
                  Colors.cyanAccent,
                  Colors.blue,
                  Colors.lime,
                  Colors.lightGreen,
                );
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child: isSelected(
                  'Main Theme',
                  iconProvider.primary1 == Colors.deepPurpleAccent
                      ? true
                      : false)),
          Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 3,
            color: Colors.lime,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 7,
          ),
          InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                iconProvider.changeIcons(
                  Colors.white70,
                  Colors.white,
                  Colors.pinkAccent,
                  Colors.pink,
                  Colors.tealAccent,
                  Colors.teal,
                  Colors.amberAccent,
                  Colors.redAccent,
                );
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child: isSelected('Secondary Theme',
                  iconProvider.primary1 == Colors.white70 ? true : false)),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget isSelected(String text, bool selected) {
    if (selected) {
      return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(6),
        child: Text(text,
            style: GoogleFonts.anton(color: Colors.lime, fontSize: 24)),
      );
    } else {
      return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(6),
        child: Text(text,
            style: GoogleFonts.anton(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 24)),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you include minimal snippet on question?

Comment: Okay I added some code, sorry it's my first question so formatting was an issue.

Comment: Sorry I am not getting what exactly you are trying to archive

Comment: Basically whenever the NotifyListners() function is called in IconProvider, it doesn't change the colors, the colors remain the exact same, but if you click on one of the buttons then it will change, I need them to change as soon as NotifyListners is used.

Comment: sorry I am not getting about function calls, others may help